# Checkbox with unicode symbol for Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, unicode

I'm trying to do a Component for Selectors (checkboxes and radios) using just css and unicode symbols as style. Instead of the default style.

I used different unicodes:

[image: selectors]

Code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/unicode-selectors?file=index.js

Is working fine, but not in Firefox (And maybe in other browsers)...

In Firefox these unicode symbols have different size and is very ugly. Can somebody help me to solve this?

In Firefox:

[image: inFirefox]

Here is the code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/unicode-selectors?file=index.js

**Selector Component**

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import './styles.scss'

export default function Selector({
  id, children, labelProps, selectorType, ...props
}) {
  const labelClassName = labelProps.className
  const selector = (
    <>
      <input
        className={`${selectorType}-hidden`}
        id={id}
        type={selectorType}
        {...props}
      />
      <span className="mask" />
    </>
  )

  /* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/label-has-for */
  return (
    <label
      htmlFor={id}
      {...labelProps}
      className={`${selectorType}-selector ${labelClassName}`}
    >
      {children ? children(selector) : selector}
    </label>
  )
  /* eslint-enable jsx-a11y/label-has-for */
}

Selector.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  labelProps: PropTypes.objectOf(PropTypes.any),
  children: PropTypes.func,
  selectorType: PropTypes.oneOf(['radio', 'checkbox']),
}

Selector.defaultProps = {
  labelProps: {},
  children: undefined,
  selectorType: 'radio',
}
```

**Styles**

```
.radio-selector, .checkbox-selector {
  cursor: pointer;
  min-width: 16px;
  min-height: 16px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;

  .radio-hidden, .checkbox-hidden {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
  }

  .mask {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;

    &.margin-left {
      margin-left: 10px
    }
    &.margin-right {
      margin-right: 10px
    }
  }
}

.radio-selector {
  .radio-hidden ~ .mask::before {
    font-family: system-ui;
    content: '◯';
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  .radio-hidden:checked ~ .mask::before {
    font-family: system-ui;
    content: '◉';
    font-size: 15px;
  }

  .radio-hidden:disabled ~.mask::before {
    color: #b6b6b6;
    cursor: default;
  }

  &:hover .radio-hidden:not(:disabled):not(:checked) ~ .mask::before {
    color: #dd7758;
  }
}

.checkbox-selector {
  .checkbox-hidden ~ .mask::before {
    font-family: system-ui;
    content: '□';
    font-size: 17px;
  }

  .checkbox-hidden:checked ~ .mask::before {
    font-family: system-ui;
    content: '■';
    font-size: 17px;
  }

  .checkbox-hidden:checked ~ .mask::after {
    font-family: system-ui;
    content: '\2713';
    color: #fff;
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    font-weight: 100;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 1px 0 0 -15px;
  }

  .checkbox-hidden:disabled ~.mask::before {
    color: #b6b6b6;
    cursor: default;
  }

  &:hover .checkbox-hidden:not(:disabled):not(:checked) ~ .mask::before {
    color: #dd7758;
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
  <Selector defaultChecked selectorType="checkbox">
    {
      selector => (
        <>
          {selector}
          {` Check me`}
        </>
      )
    }
  </Selector>
```

Thank you so much to help me!

Comment: Could try using the ballot box with a check? https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2611/index.htm

Answer (score 2):

It's a couple of CSS issue

When you have absolute positioning of a tag it should be generally wrapped into a tag with `position: relative` and you should always specify the position per instance as `top:0; left:0`. You can also hide the actual check with `display: none` as the height:0; with:0 will not work as you expect in different browsers. That's all you need to do to make your check boxes compatible with different browsers.

Comment: I fixed now this :) thanks! https://stackblitz.com/edit/unicode-selectors?file=index.js However, the issue in Firefox is still existing. I think is more related with the size of the unicode symbol :(

Comment: Yep, you should probably use a web font as FontAwesome where you can also find beautiful icons for checkboxes. It's good to set also the `width` and `height` of the ::before and ::after and `line-height` icons to avoid displacements but keep in mind that the size of the icon is set by the `font-size`. but the icon container should be placed correctly so the W/H set will make you container predictable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with Firefox was the `font-family: system-ui`. Instead, using these font-family with all the corresponding fallbacks is working correctly:

```css
font-family: -apple-system, system-ui, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
```

The working code is here:

- https://stackblitz.com/edit/unicode-selectors-vezpvs?file=Selector%2Fstyles.scss